# Running “ssh -X” to a macOS/XQuartz from Windows 10 not working as expected

Tags: windows-10, macos, ssh, x-windows

I'm trying to transfer graphics via SSH and X11 server..
The server is running on an iMac running macOS 10.14
The client is a SSH console in Windows 10...
(tested with ssh -X and ssh -Y, and set the DISPLAY env-var)

X-Server on the Windows side is XMing...

This works great with any version of Linux.
Even with Raspberry Pi.
But I can’t get this to work with macOS...

When I invoke a Mac app (like Notes or TextEdit)
 
in SSH client (Windows side)
...
the app just opens in macOS desktop?!

Any ideas why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

Apps like Notes or TextEdit use Apple's library for the GUI. They don't use X, so nothing gets forwarded via `ssh`.

And BTW, you got the setup wrong. If you are on machine A and ssh with X forwarding into machine B, then the X **clients** run on machine B, while the **server** runs on machine A.

So it's irrelevant whether there's an X server running on the iMac, or not. The only thing that matters is the XMing server on Windows, and that you need to start programs that actually use X on the iMac.

If you want to access native MacOS applications, you need another method of forwarding graphics, e.g. VNC. That will give you the complete desktop in one window, though, not single applications.

Comment: I use VNC for the OSX/Remote control...
Also tried to install FreeRDP+XQuartz in OSX 
to acess via MSTSC.exe/RDP but with no success...

Comment: So what you are saying is that because OSX uses a proprietary GUI-Library that do not use X11 there is no way to forward a window to the remote X-Server via SSH???

Comment: Once more: You don't "forward the remote X server". You install different versions of XQuartz on OS X until you are blue in the face, it won't change a thing. X uses protocol between client and server that is "network transport", and ssh just forwards that. And yes, unless you run an application that's an actual X client und would normally use XQuartz on the OS X (you can install some of those via homebrew), there's no way to forward windows of non-X-clients.

Comment: Well... huuummm... I humbly discord... since the window is being generated in the ssh server (running under OSX) by the running program... and then '''forwarded''' to the ssh client (switched by the -X or -Y arguments)... where the X-Server is running (XMing in this case,,, as I state in the question)... ... ... ... but if you don't believe me... just do the same test as I did... and turn off the iMac ;-)

Comment: Anyway it was a technical question about the underpinnings of the OSX/GUI... I had already tested with the apps that are installed with XQuartz (the XLogo/XEyes/and XTerminal)... and everything runs OK...